# Somehow indicate last line in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I have a macro that I use to highlight lines of to do lists to see which step I am on.  It's pretty simple.  It unhighlights the current line and highlights the next line.

```
Sub Highlight_Next_Row_Down()
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
End Sub
```

Now, I want it to just unhighlight the current line when I am on the last line of the document, because then I am finished.  I would do this by inserting an if statement around the whole thing (minus the sub statements) which first checks if it's the last line.  But, I don't know how to check if a line is the last line.  I have googled and haven't found anything.

Similarly, I have a "Highlight_Next_Row_Up" and I want to know how to do the same when I reach the top line.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the exact logic you need but this code presenting one of possible way of checking if you are in last line of document.

```
Sub Highlight_Next_Row_Down()
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
    'here check if this is the end
    If Selection.End = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc").Range.End Then
        'just unhighlight
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
    Else
        'your code here
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    End If
End Sub
```

Please keep in mind that any additional empty paragraph moves `end of document` somewhere below your the last line of your TEXT.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to looking at this.  This seems to be just what I wanted.  I appreciate your help.  And, it's simple enough that I was able to make the necessary changes to Highlight_Next_Row_Up.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach one could take is to set take advantage of the MoveDown method's ability to return a variable.  If, instead of:

Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1 ,

you write:

c = Selection.MoveDown(wdLine,1) ,

then the variable c will assume a value equal to however many units the selection actually moves.  So, as long as the selection is in the body of the text, it moves down one line and c = 1.  Whereas, at the end of text, the selection can't move down another line, and so c = 0.  That way you set up a simpler control condition:

If c = 0 then...

Do until c = 0...

etc